# api request with postman

Tags: c#, api

I have a mvc application. And I am using a API for retrieving. teachers.

This is the class:

```
[Authorize(Roles = IdentityRoles.Teacher)]
    [RoutePrefix("api//current")]
    public sealed class CurrentTeacherController : ApiControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ICurrentTeacherProcess _currentTeacherProcess;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor.
        /// </summary>
        public CurrentTeacherController(ICurrentTeacherProcess process)
        {
            _currentTeacherProcess = process;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the teacher data of the current user
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The TeacherDto of the current teacher</returns>
        [Route("")]
        [HttpGet]
        public TeacherDto GetTeacher()
        {
            return _currentTeacherProcess.GetTeacher();
        }

}
```

And I am using Postman for retriving a teacher. For example teacher with id: 1001.

And In Postman I put this:

```
http://localhost:6598/api/register/

But I get a : 404 not found exception.
```

This is the startup.cs file:

```
 public sealed class Startup
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Configures the application for use with OWIN. This method is called implicitly by Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app"><see cref="IAppBuilder" />implementation.</param>
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

            WebApiConfig.Register(config);

            var container = AutofacConfig.Register(config);

            app.UseAutofacLifetimeScopeInjector(container);

            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Hallo",
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                TokenValidationParameters = ApiGatewaySecurityTokenHandler.CreateTokenValidationParameters(
                    "hoi", "hoi", IdentityRoles.Duo, IdentityRoles.Competent, IdentityRoles.Berichtenbox),
                TokenHandler = container.Resolve<JwtSecurityTokenHandler>()
            });

            app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.PostAuthenticate);

            app.UseMiddlewareFromContainer<ApiGatewayMiddleware>();

            app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
```

update with startup.cs file

Comment: I really can't understand what your controller is doing

Comment: Why exactly you think `api/register/teachers/current` would match `api/register/teachers/current/diploma/1001/`?

Answer (score 1):

You get a 404 because a handler doesn't exist in your API for that request. You need to add the id to your API route like so

```
[Route("{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public TeacherDto GetTeacher(int  id/* or other type if you aren't using int as your primary key*/ )
{
    return _currentTeacherProcess.GetTeacher(id);
}
```

And your request should be:

```
http://localhost:6598/api/register/teachers/current/1001
```

Comment: Thank you. But that is not the point. Because if I do a get in post man I get this message:{"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}. But I am already logged in

Comment: maybe you are not sending the cookie or token of your authorization in your http request, what type of authorization you are using?

Comment: This:  [Authorize(Roles = IdentityRoles.Teacher)]

Comment: Okay you are using the Identity cookie authentication, do you have the authentication cookie produced by your application in Postman? Normally you define you Application cookie name on your startup.cs file not quite sure which name is by default, but make sure postman has it

Comment: This is completely off topic of you question since you don't have the authorization fully working